# Can you check if my alternative proof is correct, and if not, tell me why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, field-theory

I have a homework problem to prove that if $F$ is a field, $p(x)$ is in $F[x]$, and $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $F[x]$, then $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$. My book provides an answer, and going through it I understand it, but I thought of a possible alternative proof and I wanted to know if anyone could check if this is correct?

My proof is that since $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is maximal, $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a field, and thus an integral domain. That implies that $p(x)$ is prime, and hence irreducible.

It seems a lot simpler than what the book gave (shown in pic), which made me suspicious that it might not be right. Thanks to anyone who helps!

[image]

Comment: I think your proof is correct.

Comment: I made your pseudo-math into LaTeX form. Can you check if it is what you intended to write?

Comment: Yes, it's a common proof, e.g. see the linked dupe. Please note that for a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.  It's best to delete this quesiton since we already have too many posts on this FAQ.